# How can I dynamically update a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<div class="g-popupgrid-item g-zoom" data-size="395x385">
```

I want to populate the 395x385 dynamically with the image size.

I have a JS function which gets the image size, I don't know how to print/echo/document.write it to be within the HTML tag.

Comment: you won't print/echo/document.write. you use DOM and `.setAttribute()` in jquery. it's as simple as `$('.g-popupgrid-item .g-zoom').attr('data-size', var_with_value_you_want)`

Comment: And of course, you can do this without jQuery:  document.querySelector("g-popupgrid-item g-zoom").setAttribute("data-size", your_value_here);

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using `jQuery` for such a trivial task unless you are already using it in your project.   Plain javascript:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.g-popupgrid-item');
var newSize = '100x100'; // for example
div.setAttribue('data-size', newSize);
```

Comment: or using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) in compatible browsers `div.dataset.size = newSize`

Answer (score 2):

Get the `Node` using JavaScript, then modify it to fit your needs:

```
var container = document.querySelector(".g-popupgrid-item .g-zoom")
container.setAttribute("data-size", value)
```

Keep in mind this will only affect the first element with those classes, if you want affect them all, use the code below:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".g-popupgrid-item .g-zoom")
containers.forEach(function(container) {
  container.setAttribute("data-size", value)
})
```

Also keep in mind that `containers` is not an `Array` it's a `NodeList`. Read more [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

**EDIT**: According to @Eoin, the `.forEach()` method on `NodeList`s is not supported in Firefox. You can also use a standard `for` loop in place of it:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".g-popupgrid-item .g-zoom")
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containers[i].setAttribute("data-size", value)
}
```

Comment: You point out a nice feature of returning a `NodeList` rather than the `HTMLCollection` that `getElementsByClassName` produces - the `forEach` method. You don't need to recast as an array.

Comment: @Damon I just read a bunch about the differences between `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection`, because it was one of the things that I really didn't understand about browser js. Good timing on @Eoin 's part, though

Comment: I have tried to implement it but now I'm getting an error

`TypeError: containers.forEach is not a function`

here's my full code

Comment: `<script>
 var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
       images[i].addEventListener("load", (event) => {
     var image = event.target;
     image.dataset.size = image.naturalWidth + "x" + image.naturalHeight;
     console.log(image.dataset.size);
   });//works at this point, then I add the next part
    var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".g-popupgrid-item .g-zoom");
  containers.forEach(function(container) {
  container.setAttribute("data-size", image.dataset.size);
  });  
 } 
  </script>`

Comment: The error doesn't appear in Chrome console only in Firefox.

Comment: @Eoin it's an issue of browser compatability. You can also use a standard `for` loop, which will work in Firefox

Comment: In any case neither browser seem to replace the data-size attribute.  But I will try to change it to a for loop instead.  Thanks for the response.